# Powershell compare-object

Tags: powershell

I trying to make a script which compare two directory ( source, destination) and if there are a difference on destination, copy files from source to destination.
The problem is that I don't know how copy the tree of files too.

Example:

```
$s = "C:\source\client"
$t = "C:\destination\client"

$target = Get-ChildItem $t -Recurse
$source = get-childitem $s -Recurse
Compare-Object $source $target -Property Name , Length |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } |
    foreach-object -process{
        copy-item $_.FullName -destination $t
}
```

If I have a file in source ( C:\source\client\bin\file.txt) and not in the destination folder, how is the code to copy the file in C:\destination\client\bin\file.txt ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything you are trying to preserve in the `$t` directory? You could just do a copy outright as well. `Copy-Item -Path $s -Destination $t -recurse -Force` This would not be ideal if the directories are very large. This comment is more about my first question than the `copy-item` remark.

Comment: I just want to copy the file(s) or folder(s) returned by compare-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the process of testing this more. From what i can see the logic of your code is sound.

```
Compare-Object $source $target -Property Name , Length |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject |
    foreach-object -process{
        copy-item $_.FullName -destination $t
}
```

Once you have the compare done pipe the results after the `Where` in `Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject` to extract the File item so that you can see the `FullName` property

Answer (score 1):

copy-item has a -recurse parameter that will let you specify the root of a directory and then copy everything below it

```
copy-item c:\test d:\test -recurse -force
```

Edit:
The problem is for repeated tasks you can't stop it from trying to overwrite everything. You can add -force to make it do it, but it is not very efficient.

Alternatively (and probably a better and simpler way to go about this) you could call robocopy with the /mir switch

Comment: For the robocopy that is assuming the OP wants to overwrite preexisting files. In the questions it would only copy files if they dont exist in the target. Robocopy would copy if the files are different in the target as well. I would guess robocopy is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree...was actually editing my answer to state that as you commented. Just wanted to answer his initial question at least before I suggested an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing.  Here is what I have done with everything I searched to compare MD5 and then copy only newly added and different files.

With [Compare contents of two folders using PowerShell Get-FileHash] from http://almoselhy.azurewebsites.net/2014/12/compare-contents-of-two-folders-using-powershell-get-filehash/

```
$LeftFolder = "D:\YFMS_Target"
$RightFolder = "D:\YFMS_Copy"
$LeftSideHash = @(Get-ChildItem $LeftFolder -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5| select @{Label="Path";Expression={$_.Path.Replace($LeftFolder,"")}},Hash)
$RightSideHash = @(Get-ChildItem $RightFolder -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5| select @{Label="Path";Expression={$_.Path.Replace($RightFolder,"")}},Hash)
robocopy $LeftFolder $RightFolder /e /xf *
Write-Host "robocopy LastExitCode: $LastExitCode"
if ($LastExitCode -gt 7) { exit $LastExitCode } else { $global:LastExitCode = $null }
Compare-Object $LeftSideHash $RightSideHash -Property Path,Hash | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | foreach { Copy-Item -LiteralPath (Join-Path $LeftFolder $_.Path) -Destination (Join-Path $RightFolder $_.Path) -verbose}
```